# Jquery to select the UNIQUE next Table row

Tags: php, jquery

```
echo "
                <tr>
                    <td id='trigger'>".$firstName."</td>
                    <td>".$lastName."</td>
                    <td>".$phone."</td>
                    <td>".$email."</td>
                    <td>".$dob."</td>
                    <td>".$emp_income."</td>
                    <td>".$dateIn."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='hide'>
                    <td colspan=7>Address: ".$address." Province: ".$prov." Postal Code: ".$post." RentOrOwn: ".$rent_or_own." House Payment: ".$house_payment." Shopping: ".$shopping." Employer:".$emp_name." Job Title: ".$emp_title." Employment Time: ".$emp_time." Downpayment: ".$downpayment." </td>
                </tr>
                ";
```

So the above is being spit out by a loop iterating a database - the first TD class='trigger' is what I want to click to reveal the hidden row data calss='hide'

```
$('#trigger').on('click',() => {
    $('#trigger').closest('tr').next('tr').toggleClass('hide');
})
```

is what I've tried along with a few other things - prob is that not EACH name in the table is clickable ( and clearly I'm appending class='trigger' to each iteration, second issue is that when I do click the first name in the first row they ALL unhide...

Comment: First off, you're creating invalid markup with `<td id='trigger'>`. Ids should be unique. You should use a class instead. Secondly, `$('tr')` simply selects all the table rows. `$(this)` would contain the clicked one.

Comment: I see, regarding the id and class - so your suggesting i change the ID's to classes? please see my EDIT - I did manage to get the first row working properly but the others are not clickable?

Comment: Ok, changing that to class works SORTA - but now they all are clickable ( that's good ) but all the hiddens open... using this now  $('.trigger').on('click',() => {
  $('.trigger').closest('tr').next('tr').toggleClass('hide');
 })
when I change the second .trigger to $(this) it all stops working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code sample of solution:

```js
$('.trigger').on('click', (e) => {
    $(e.target).closest('tr').next('tr').toggleClass('hide');
})
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="trigger">First name 1</td>
        <td>Last name 1</td>
        <td>Phone 1</td>
        <td>Email 1</td>
        <td>Dob 1</td>
        <td>Emp income 1</td>
        <td>Date in 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide">
        <td colspan=7>Address 1 Province 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="trigger">First name 2</td>
        <td>Last name 2</td>
        <td>Phone 2</td>
        <td>Email 2</td>
        <td>Dob 2</td>
        <td>Emp income 2</td>
        <td>Date in 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide">
        <td colspan=7>Address 2 Province 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

The main points that have been changed:

- Class is used instead of id for trigger elements, as ids need to be unique.
- Clicked element is fetched through `e.target` - event's `target` property holds the element that triggered the event. The rest of the DOM searching function calls are unchanged.

Note that `.closest('tr')` could be replaced by `.parent()` and it would work just the same.

Comment: thank you soo much for your support. It works, HOWEVER, something strange happens now - I'm using [link]https://datatables.net/ and if you look at the top of that table the search bar and the sorting ext.. when I add that second TR into the mix it does what I want it too but I loose all the other datatable functions... any ideas I could look at? I don't know how to show pics ext here, if I remove that TR It all comes back

Comment: If you have follow-up issues, consider opening a new question. I doubt this can be resolved in comments. Try debugging it (see if there are conflicting events), if you don't find the issue, ask away.